# python: finding matches in a data structure

Tags: python

I have a data structure in this form:

```
Song = namedtuple('Song', ['fullpath', 'tags']) # tags is a dictionary
Album = namedtuple('Album', ['album_key', 'songs']) 

The data_structure is a list of Albums
```

There are thousands of albums, with 10-20 songs in each

I'm looking for matches:

```
for new_album in new_albums:
    for old_album in old_albums:
        if new_album.album_key == old_album.album_key:
            for new_song in new_album.songs:
                for old_song in old_album.songs:
                    if new_song.fullpath == old_song.fullpath:
                        # do something
                        break
```

This is inefficient, mainly because it restarts the loop through old_album for each new_album.  One solution is to use dictionaries, but I need to sort and OrderedDict is only ordered by key insertion.  Another is to change the list to a dictionary, process, then change back to a list, but that does not seem ideal.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are `album_key`s unique, or are there different albums with the same `album_key`?

Comment: Can you sort the albums?

Comment: album_keys are unique.  The list of albums is sortable.

Comment: Would it be enough to find any two songs that have the same fullpath, no matter of which album they are?

Comment: Are you sure you need to keep the list sorted? Usually, the reason for doing so is to allow binary search, but with a dictionary, search by key is already fast(er). `sorted(new_albums)` would give you the sorted list of album keys when you actually need it.

Comment: If they have the same fullpath, they are a match.

Comment: @chepner "sure" is a high standard :-)  I suppose I could maintain an index if of the list for when I need a non-standard order (dictionary for matching, then use the index when I need a particular order). I would like to see if there's a non-dictionary solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert the data into a new format, but you can still use a dict for finding matches:

```
paths = {}

for album, a_id in zip(albums, xrange(len(albums))):
    for song, s_id in zip(album.songs, xrange(len(album.songs))):
         if song.fullpath not in paths:
              paths[song.fullpath] = (a_id, s_id)
         else:
              # do something
              break
```

when you get to `#do something` you can use the `paths[song.fullpath]` to give you `[0]` (the album) and `[1]` the song that matches. so:

```
 matched_album, matched_song = paths[song.fullpath]
 print albums[matched_album].songs[matched_song], "matches!"
```

Does this help?

Comment: btw `for i, ix in zip(foo, xrange(len(foo))):` is the same as `for ix, i in enumerate(foo):`